# Random Variable Help

Tags: probability

Sort of confused on how to approach questions like this.

Suppose $X$ is a non-negative random variable and the $\mathrm{E}[X]=5$. Suppose that the maximum value that $X$ can take is $7$. Which of the following statements can you conclude from this information.

Select one:
a. $P(X=5) \gt 0$
b. $P(X\le4) \le 2/3$
c. $P(X\gt6) \le 5/7$
d. $X$ is a geometric random variable.
e. $X$ is a binomial random variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show
$$
\mathrm{E}[X]\le a\mathrm{P}[X\le a]+\max(X)\mathrm{P}[X\gt a]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It's possible that $X$ only takes on values $0$ and $7$, with probabilities $P(X = 0) = 2/7$, $P(X = 7) = 5/7$. So does $X$ have to be geometric or binomial, and does $X$ have to equal $5$ with positive probability? If you can rule that out, then try to use inequalities on $E(X)$ in terms of $P(X \geq a)$ and $P(X \leq b)$ to derive the answer.